# Providing user parameters in azure active directory authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have created a azure web application. This application has been enabled with azure active directory authentication. When authentication process starts first the user email is asked. If I already know the user email address can this step be avoided. In the process if I already have user email id, it should directly go to next step. How this can be controlled from web application?

Comment: I think @JasonPan 's solution meets your requirement, please accept it. Only you accept answers on time, others will be more willing to assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample login url:**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=......XXXXXXXXXXXXXX...T45&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0
```

**You can attach:** `&login_hint=emailid`.

## See my gif.

[image]

## Offical doc

[Request an authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code)